# Using RabbitMQ with Django to get information from internal servers

Tags: python, linux, django, sockets

I've been trying to make a decision about my student project before going further. The main idea is get disk usage data, active linux user data, and so on from multiple internal server and publish them with Django.

Before I came to RabbitMQ I was thinking about developing a client application for each linux server and geting this data through a socket. But I want to make that student project simple. Also, I don't know how difficult it is to make a socket connection via Django.

So, I thought I could solve my problem with RabbitMQ without socket programming. Basically, I send a message to rabbit queue. Then get whatever I want from the consumer server.

On the Django side, the client will select one of the internal servers and click the "details" button. Then I want to show this information on web page.

I already read almost all documentation about rabbitmq, celery and pika. Sending messages to all internal servers(clients) and the calculation of information that I want to get is OKAY but I can't figure out how I can put this data on a webpage with Django?

How would you figure out that problem if you were me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved my problem own my own. Solution is RabbitMQ RPC call. You can execute your python code on remote server and get result of process via RPC requests. Details can ben found here.

http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-six-python.html

Thank you guys.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you already done the hard work(celery, rabbit, etc) but missing Django basics. Go through the polls tutorial and [getting started with django](http://gettingstartedwithdjango.com/) or the many other resources on the web, and It would be quite simple.  Basically:

create the models (objects represented in db)
   declare urls
   setup views to pass the data from the model to the webpage template
   create the templates (or do it with client side framework and create a JSON response)

**EDIT:** (after you clarified the question)  Actually I just hit the same problem too. The answer is running **another** python process parallel to the Django process (in the same virtualenv) in this process you can set up a rabbit consumer (using pica, puka, kombu or whatever) and calling specific Django functions/methods to do something with the information from rabbitmq.  you can also just call celery tasks from there to be executed in the Django app context.

a `procfile` for example (just illustrating, you can run both process in many other ways):

```
web: python manage.py runserver
worker: python listen_from_servers.py
```

Notice that you'll have to set the `DJANGO_SETTIGNS_MODULE` for the settings file enviroment variable for django imports to work.

Comment: Thank you for your replay alonisser. i already know basics of Django and i believe that i can do what you described but i cant understand/imagine "how can i get information from my clients(internal servers) ?" . Each workers will get message from RabbitMQ and do some process. than how can i reach result of process from django side ?

Comment: Might be this can help you http://simondlr.com/post/24479818721/basic-django-celery-and-rabbitmq-example

Answer (score 0):

You need the following two programs running at all times:

1. The producer, which will populate the queue. This is the program that will collect the various messages and then post them on the queue.
2. The consumer, which will process messages from the queue. This consumer's job is to read the message and do *something* with it; so that it is processed and removed from the queue. The function that this consumer does is entirely up to you, but what you want to do in this scenario is write information from the message to a database model; the same database that is part of your django app.

As the producer pushes messages and the consumer removes them from the queue, your database will get updated.

On the django side, the process is simply to filter this database and display records for a particular machine. As such, django does not need to be aware of how the records are being populated in the database - all django is doing is fetching, filtering, sending to the template and rendering the views.

The question comes how best (well actually, easily) populate the databases.  You can do it the traditional way, by using Python's well documentation DB-API and write your own SQL statements; but since celery is so well integrated with django - you can use the django's ORM to do this work for you as well.

I hope this gets you going in the right direction.